# Run-time Error '9' - subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

When running my macro, I keep getting a run-time error stating the subscript is out of range. Anyone have any pointers? The line that is not working is the 
***Application.Workbooks(3).Activate***

Below is the macro..

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
  ActiveSheet.Unprotect
  ActiveSheet.Name = "M-YTD"
    Range("E16:H16").Select
    Selection.MergeCells = False
    Columns("B:G").Select
    Range("G11").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveSheet.Name = "VarianceRpt"
    Rows("1:10").Select
    Range("A10").Activate
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Columns("G:G").ColumnWidth = 50
    Range("G18").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Variance Notes"
    Range("F19").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("G18:G19").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("D16:F16").Select
    Selection.MergeCells = True
    ActiveSheet.Previous.Select
    Range("E16:H16").Select
    Selection.MergeCells = True
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Transfers"
    Windows("Var Template.xls").Activate
    Range("A1:M37").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Application.Workbooks(3).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("VarianceRpt").Select
    Sheets("VarianceRpt").Move Before:=Sheets(1)
End Sub
```

Comment: You probably will want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Do you have 3 workbooks open when you run this? I'd suggest reading through [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/4088852) and tracking your object references.

Comment: You need to explicitly state what you mean by `Workbooks(3)`. Recording a macro is a great place for beginners to get a starting point, but these tend to require a lot of editing down and tweaking to get to the final product.

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially a typo. a *Subscript out of Range* error always means that you're trying to index an array/collection with an invalid index parameter, in other words, the index you're asking for doesn't exist because it's outside the bounds of the sequence.

`Application.Workbooks(3)` means the *third* `Workbook` object belonging to the current `Application` instance. If the current `Application` instance contains 2 or fewer `Workbooks`, then any index value greater than or equal to 3 will raise the error. Likewise, an index of 0 will raise the same error.

The same is true for any `Collection` type, the `index` parameter must be greater than 0, and less than or equal to the length of the collection. So:

- `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(0)` will fail since `0` is not a valid index
- `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(13)` will fail if there are 12 or fewer `Worksheets`
- `ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)` will fail if there aren't at least *one* `ListObject` on the worksheet

Arrays are usually base-zero, which means that their indices begin at 0, as a result their upper bound is 1 less than their length, so an array like:

```
Dim myArray
myArray = Array("A", "B", "C", "D")
```

Will have an upper bound of 3, and a lower bound of 0. Valid indices are therefore within the range of 0 to 3, so:

- `myArray(4)` will raise the error
- `myArray(0)` will return the value "A"

One sort-of exception is the `Range.Cells` collection, which actually works differently:

- `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Cells(2)` refers to cell "A2"

Answer (score 0):

In human language this error would be "You want me (Excel, or Application) to go to the third open workbook and activate it. But I have less than 3 workbooks. So, I show you this 
ugly error. Sorry :("